# print file writer only writes 1 number

Tags: java, user-defined-functions, printwriter

I am building a small software in java to test both functions and PrintWriter method. But When I run it only the last number of the loop is printed. For example on the Odd file only 99 is printed and on the Even file only 100.

I created a couple of system.out.println to test if the loop was working and it seems it is. Does anyone know why it is only printing one line?

```
   /**
 *
 * @author bertadevant
 */

import java.io.*;

public class Filewritermethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       Numbers();  

   }

   public static void Numbers () throws IOException {

        for (int i =1; i<=100; i++){

            EvenOdd(i);
        }
}

    public static void EvenOdd (int n) throws IOException {

        File Odd = new File ("odd.txt");
        File Even = new File ("even.txt");
        File All = new File ("all.txt");

        PrintWriter all = new PrintWriter (All);

        all.println(n);
        all.close();

        if (n%2==0){

            PrintFile(Even, n);
            System.out.println ("even");
        }

        else {
            PrintFile (Odd, n);
            System.out.println ("odd");
        }

    }

    public static void PrintFile (File filename, int n) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (filename);

        if (n!=0) {
            pw.println(n);
            System.out.println (n + " printfile method");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println ("The number is not valid");
        }

        pw.close();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this:

1. open file
2. write number
3. close file
4. start over by going to (1).

This way, you are clearing the previous data of the file. Change your logic to:

1. open file
2. write number
3. goto (2)
4. when done, close file.

---

Alternatively, you could choose to write to the file by appending data. But that is **not recommended** in this scenario. If you would like to try it (only for educational purposes!), you could try to create your PrintWriters like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `PrintWriter` overwrites existing files. In your `PrintFile` method, you create a new `PrintWriter` object for every write. This means that you override everything you’ve written before in the `PrintFile` method. Therefore the file only contains the last write. To solve this, use a shared `PrintWriter` instance.

Please note that by convention,  methods, fields and variables in Java start with small letters (`numbers()`, `evenOdd(...)`, `printFile(...)`, `odd`, `even`, `file` ...). This makes your code more readable for others.